# Bing Maps Silverlight - Adding tooltips to pins generated in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, bing-maps, tooltip

I am attempting to convert a bing map implementation that uses standard PushPins in order to populate the map, but I need to add a tooltip to each pin. I found some options of how to do this on the website but the issue is I need the pushpins to be different from each other in a way that is dynamic. Based on the properties of each pin it must have a different background color.

The code already on this site all has the programmer use an image of the pushpin when they customize it.

So right now I need a way to either create a templated pushpin that is able to maintain the look and properties of a pushpin (so I can set background), while allowing a tooltip. Or instead having a regular pushpin have a tooltip or popup with it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edited:

Control Template I am using

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NewPins" >

        <Grid x:Name="pushPin" >

            <Popup IsOpen="False" behaviors:RolloverPopup.HideDelay="0" behaviors:RolloverPopup.Target="{Binding ElementName=pushPin}"  Margin="30,-20,0,0"  >
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
```

This is setting up the pin in C#

```
Pushpin pin = new Pushpin() 
                    { 
                        Location = new Location( Double.Parse(item.PinLat), Double.Parse(item.PinLong)),
                        Content=String.Concat( GetNewlineString(item.LocationName), GetNewlineString(item.CallerName), GetNewlineString(item.PhoneNumber)),
                        Template=(ControlTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["NewPins"],
                        Width = 50,
                        Height = 65,
                    };
```

And this is creating the Bing Map

```
<c:BingMapAdSmart 
         AnimationLevel="UserInput"
         Pins="{Binding DashboardViewModel.MapPins}" 
         NavigationVisibility="Visible"
         SetViewZoomFactor="0"
         MaxZoomLevel="7"
         Visibility="{Binding NavViewModel.IsViewTransitioning, Converter={StaticResource TrueToCollapsedConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this issue to my complete satisfaction. To accomplish this, you need to have to create a Pushpin style with a key. Then inside this pushpin you create a standard pushpin (you can use another style on that but don't let it look back to this style, I used default), and a popup to go along with it. An example is below, I am using a local tool to do easy rollover popups, otherwise its standard stuff + bind maps.

```
<Style TargetType="bingMaps:Pushpin" x:Key="NewPins2">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="bingMaps:Pushpin" >

                <Grid x:Name="pushPin" >
                    <Border  Width="50" Height="65" >
                        <bingMaps:Pushpin Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    </Border>

                    <Popup IsOpen="False" behaviors:RolloverPopup.HideDelay="0" behaviors:RolloverPopup.Target="{Binding ElementName=pushPin}"  Margin="30,-20,0,0"  >
                        <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not really understand your question correctly, but i assume you need pushpins that are being created dynamically based on a template right? And you want to be able to change the tooltip (content property i assume) independently.

If thats the case, first you need to put a template resource to your resources in xaml;

```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
       <ControlTemplate x:Key="template_name" TargetType="m:Pushpin">
            ...this is your design part you can compile this xaml via Expression
       </ControlTemplate>
   </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

then you'll need pass this value to every pushpin you've created dynamically codebehind. On this stage you can also set their content property, since they don't have a notification property, i don't know if you mean this but content property is the similar one. You can edit them like you edit other stuff;

```
   myPushPin.template = (ControlTemplate)This.Resources["template_name"];
   myPushPin.Content = "Hello World!";
```

This stage may differ according where you put your resources if its in phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources

if you put in Application.Resources
use this;

```
   myPushPin.template = (ControlTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["template_name"];
   myPushPin.Content = "Hello World!";
```

This should work, i don't have bing maps API or WP7 tools installed on this computer so i can't test it but this should be ok.

Happy coding!

---

Edit:
So if you want to change the background of a pushpin you don't have to hold back, it doesn't matter whether it has a control template or not. Actually every control has one as default. You can change the background as you always do

```
   myPushpin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

Comment: Essentially I have two problems 1. I must have pins with dynamically determined colors associated with them that is always shown on the pin and 2. There must be a tooltip you can activate to gather additional information. The problem is that all Tooltip solutions I have seen use a Control Template, but when you utilize a control template it requires you to choose your own image which prevents need number 1.

Comment: Correct me if i understood you wrong but you can use Control Template and change the backgrounds dynamically at the same time. Control Templates are also implemented as default. You can use this in codebehind to change the background color: myPushPin.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue); i'm also adding this to my answer to be viewed more clealy. Apperantly i can't newline in comments :S

Comment: I see what you are doing now, and I am trying to recreate it. The code I took over was doing it slightly differently and causing the problem. I have one concern though as the template isn't saving.

Comment: You have to use another codeblock to save a control template you've created in codebehind to resources for a later use. But i'm not really sure it would be good idea to create lots of templates for user input in a mobile with limited resources, if you're trying to save the color properties you should look for an alternative like storing in a database if you have one or a service. But thats my opinion i'm not that experienced with mobile development.

Comment: I fixed what I mentioned above and it seems to be working now, atleast the code is. But nothing is appearing in the map, I know the pins have content though. I am setting location, content, template. Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: Also as a note, this is for web development, not phone development

Comment: I'm absolutely sorry! I don't know why but i thought its for wp7 and gave info about that, and thinking you're implementing on that... Anyway can you show the code you're implementing. You can edit your question and put there.

Answer (score 0):

I have done exactly what you describe. The way i did this makes the most sense to me. Here is what I did:

- I created a custom Pushpin (i.e. UserControl). This Xaml defines my custom pushpin. It assumes this pushpin is to be data-bound to. One of the binded properties is background Color. This will easily satisfy your dynamic color issue.
- In the bing map control i defined the following:
- The MyPushpinTemplate is defined in the UserControl.Resources like this:

MyPushpinControl is the UserControl.

- I also have a data model class (that implements INotifyPropertyChanged). This class is bound to an instance of MyPushpinControl. this data model class has all the properties and is data-binded to the UserControl.

This is technically all you need to know.
To satisfy your tooltip issue, I simply added a tooltip to one of the panels within my custom pushpin. Simple as that.

Comment: It looks like you meant to add in something after those colons, did something not get added to your post? It looks like they might be examples and I could really use those.

Answer (score 0):

Until I have a better solution I have decided the only thing I can think to do is to create a number of different pins to use. I don't need an infinite color solution so about 15 different pins should do the trick. Messy but it will work.